# What is the significance of "Munchkin" in Witcher?

Tags: the-witcher

I've been playing *The Witcher 3* recently and enjoying it quite a bit. One of the achievements in the game is [Munchkin](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Witcher_3_achievements) if you reach level 35. Why was this name chosen for the achievement? Does it mean something special in the Witcher universe? When I think of munchkins I think of small relatively powerless beings like what you'd find in [Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munchkin).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While writing the question I think I discovered the answer. When I was linking to munchkins from the Oz books I noticed a [Munchkin (disambiguation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munchkin_(disambiguation)) link. One of those disambiguation articles is about using the term [munchkin in the context of role playing games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munchkin_(role-playing_games)). Here is a quote from that article:

> In gaming, a munchkin is a player who plays what is intended to be a non-competitive game (usually a role-playing game) in an aggressively competitive manner. A munchkin seeks within the context of the game to amass the greatest power, score the most "kills", and grab the most loot ...

It seems to me that this is what the dev's had in mind while naming the achievement, considering that level 35 would have been quite high in base game since the recommended level for the [last couple story quests](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/On_Thin_Ice) is level 30 and the [game punishes players 6+ levels above the recommendation](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/XP) by awarding virtually no experience.

So I don't think the term munchkin has any special significance in the Witcher universe. I think it is a reference to a gaming term I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer I was going to give. The name of the achievement refers to the player, rather than anything in-universe.